# How to insert image into mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

i am trying to get the uploaded image inserted into mysql database but i get this error msg. help please. here is the error i get

```
Array
(
    [name] => Zonsondergang.jpg
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpU9qSru
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 71189
)
```

data/Zonsondergang.jpg test file successfully loaded

> Warning: file_get_contents(/tmp/phpU9qSru) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/meer/domains/skyup.nl/public_html/upload_Class/upload.php on line 68
>   Error! Failed to insert the file1

here is my code for uploading image and inserting the image into database

```
include('../inc/con_inc.php');

// Defining Class
$uploaded = new upload;

// Set Max Size
$uploaded->set_max_size(350000);

// Set Directory
$uploaded->set_directory("data");

// Set Temp Name 
$uploaded->set_tmp_name($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

// Set file size, 
$_FILES['file']['size'] is automaticly get the size
$uploaded->set_file_size($_FILES['file']['size']);


// Set File Type,
 $_FILES['file']['type'] 
$uploaded->set_file_type($_FILES['file']['type']);

// Set File Name, 
$uploaded->set_file_name($_FILES['file']['name']);


// Start Copy Process
$uploaded->start_copy();


$name=($_FILES['file']['name']);
$data=(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));


$query="INSERT INTO download(name,data) VALUES('$name','$data')";
if ($result){
 echo 'Success! Your file was successfully added!';
 }else{
 echo 'Error! Failed to insert the file' ;
 $result=mysql_query($query) or die ('query fout');

 }
```

here is the stracture of table:

```
create table download (
    id int primary key not null 
auto_increment,
    name varchar(60),
    data longblob)
```

Comment: Check the folders for proper folder permissions. Also i would say its not advisable to store images in the databases and it may slow down the mysql server if you have more queries for images. Instead I would suggest to store images as flat files and just store the path and other details in the table.

Comment: It's generally considered a bad idea to insert large amounts of data such as images into a database. Why don't you move the uploaded images into a specific directory on your server and just store the path of the images in your database..

Comment: thanks that is logical i am going to store only the path

Answer (score 0):

```
$data=(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
```

you can't do that since you've just uploaded your file with the `upload` class.
you should have a method or a variable from witch you get the actual uploaded file, something like: `$uploaded->get_file()`
you should get file content from there (the file uploaded in your 'data' folder)